# Saving image drawn using networkx/matplotlib to amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, matplotlib, networkx

I have a question: is it possible to save an image drawn using networkx and matplotlib into Amazon s3?

Here's an example:

`import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
# the graph is being build....

# now i want to draw the graph.
nx.draw_networkx(g)
plt.savefig('retweet.png') # how do i save the image to amazon s3 ?
```

So how do i save the image 'retweet.png' to amazon s3?

I do not intend to start an large EC2 instance and save the file in it.

Rather, I intend to run this code at PiCloud and than save the file to amazon s3.

How do i do it ?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a separate library to store the image on s3, "simples3" http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simples3 . Quoting example from the url :

```
s = S3Bucket(bucket,access_key=access_key,secret_key=secret_key)    
s.put("retweet.png", "my content")
```